# Set Clickable option on Button from another activity

Tags: android

In My `FirstActivity` I use one Button named `mTest1Btn`. I want to set clickable true in my `SecondActivity`.

My `FirstActivity`:

```
mTest1Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test1_ btn_id);
```

and the `SecondActivitys:

```
mTest1Btn.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: you will to obtain an instance of the firstactivity in your second activity...and then set the property accordingly...also..this method is not advised...try using a preference class rather to check whether a button is clickable or not..and set its property in onResume method of your activity

Comment: The task you want to accomplish will be better if you perform it using preferences

Comment: It may not be a good approach but you can make that button static and access it using it class name in another activity and set it clickable

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to have a class that handle global values for your app (like a Config.java), in which you have something like

```
public static boolean IsButtonClickable = true;
```

In your FirstActivity, you can call this in your onCreate / onResume

```
mTest1Btn.setClickable(Config.IsButtonClickable);
```

In your SecondActivity, modify the Config.IsButtonClickable boolean at your convenience. This way, when returning to FirstActivity, your button will be updated

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a `bundle` via `Intent`, something like this:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putBoolean("my_boolean", true);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, nextActivity);
intent.putExtra("my_bundle", args);
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve value in other activity:

```
Bundle args = getIntent().getBundleExtra("my_bundle");
boolean myBool = args.getBoolean("my_boolean");
mTest1Btn.setClickable(myBool);
```

For more details, refer to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: this is not a good approach to use Bundle extras in such cases because you loose the extras of the user presses the home button and comes back to the second activity. the Intent changes and the extras are lost.

Comment: Anything that supports your idea? I just tested and your claims are false.

Comment: ok this is happening because you activity is resuming... but suppose you had activities `1`-> `2`->`3` ->`2`  or enter activity `2` (from somewhere else) and the above code is in `1` then this will not work as expectations.